# Minimal and caracteristic polynomial of a matrix 2x2.

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials

im posting here because i cannot find anything out of here. I need a method to solve this problem:

"Write a matrix of order two wich have his caracteristic polynomial with an higher degree then the degree of his mininimal polynomial." I am honestly getting mad because i am sure it will be easy but i cannot find the solution."

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What is the minimal polynomial of the $2\times 2$ identity matrix?

Comment: Try with null matrix $A=O$.

Comment: The problem is to find the minimal polynomial, the caratteristic is easy to find but i dont know how to find the minimal. My textbook is meh...

Answer (score 1):

For a $2\times2$ matrix, the characteristic polynomial always has degree$~2$. So you want to have a minimal polynomial of degree $0$ or $1$. But degree$~0$ is not possible, since it would have to be the constant, necessarily the constant$~1$ since minimal polynomials are monic, and "evaluating" that constant polynomial at any matrix$~M$ gives $I_2$ which is not zero. (The value is independent of$~M$ exactly because the polynomial is constant). So you need to get a minimal polynomial of degree$~1$.

Any monic polynomial of degree$~1$ can be written as $X-a$ for some constant $a$, and evaluating that at some matrix$~M$ gives $M-aI_2$. So you want to find a $2\times2$ matrix $M$ such that $M-aI_2=0$ for some constant $a$. It does not require much inspiration to see that $M=aI_2$ will do, whatever value of $a$ you have chosen. Moreover, the argument above shows that these are *all* the examples that exist.